# Owl Carousel VIDEO Autoplay dosent work

Tags: jquery, video, carousel, frontend, owl-carousel

I use OWL Carousel and I want to autoplay the video (background video for the slides) but apparently owl carousel stops the video.

Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EGrGN/35/

```
    <video width="320" height="240" autobuffer controls autoplay>
```

Comment: Hi. Did the answer below work out for you?  We've tried the same function but not getting any joy across all browsers. Plays once in FF and not at all in Chrome or Safari...a little weird so looking for some pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the jQuery function `play()` in the callback afterAction:

```
 owl.owlCarousel({
    navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed: 300,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true,
    afterAction: function(current) {
        current.find('video').get(0).play();
    }
 });
```

Comment: how to stop all other videos from other non-active slides?